# convergence of series with absolute value

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

prove or show false:

if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left |a_{n}  \right |$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}a_{n}$ converges as well.

Thank you very much in advance,

Yaron.

Comment: $\frac{n+1}{n}\leq 2$ for every $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice that,

> if $\sum_{n\geq 1}|a_n|<\infty$ , then  $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n<\infty$. Also, if $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges too by [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), so we get

$$ \sum_{n \geq1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}a_n = \sum_{n \geq 1}a_n + \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{a_n}{n}< \infty.$$

Comment: @user76508: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

Show that, in fact, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {n+1\over n} a_n$ converges absolutely.  This will imply the series converges.

To show absolute convergence, you may use the Comparision test.  Note that for each $n$, one has ${n+1\over n}=1+{1\over n}\le 2$.